# Suppress strong key protection UI

Tags: c++, digital-signature, cng

Is it possible to use Microsofts cryptography function [`CryptUIWizImport`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380598(v=vs.85).aspx) without getting a UI to enter the password during sign as well as during importing the pfx file in the local system? How?

---

Details:

I have developed an application to sign the data in c++ using the private key stored on the computer. The private key is protected with Strong key protection.  I am not able to suppress the strong key protection UI. I did try with parameter `CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI` for `CryptUIWizImport`, but the UI remains. Is it possible to automate the process in back ground? How?